# Fabric.js Image scaling down below zero

Tags: fabricjs

I want to disable the scaling of image in the opposite direction, Is there any built in method for that? I could see options like lockuniscale that allows to scale image proportionally.

To be more clear, I can increase the size of image be scaling up, if i am scaling down less than zero the image will go flipped and will scale downwards, I don't want this way.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, actual no built-in method. But there is open issue on github: https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/issues/706